# How to change title style bibtex bibliography?

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex

How to change font variant of title to italics?

Currently only books have titles in italics but `misc`, `article` and `booklet` have normal font variant.

I'm using plain BIBTeX style.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

copy the file `plain.bst` to `plain-new.bst` and then
replace the `title.format` strings with `title.bformat` in all `FUNCTION`, beginning with article. but not in the `FUNCTION {format.title}`.

Alternatively you can change the `FUNCTION {format.title}` to

```
FUNCTION {format.title}
{ title empty$
    { "" }
    { title "t" change.case$ emphasize}
  if$
}
```

For a book title the case of the letters is not change, the reason why in `FUNCTION {format.btitle}` is no `change.case` function.

Save the `plain-new.bst` first in your documents directory and choose `\bibliographystyle{plain-new}` for testing.